# using aws cli how to increase and decrease the number of instances using auto scaling group

Tags: aws-cli

My auto scaling group is linked to a launch template.

Using aws cli how to I increase or decrease the desired instance count using aws cli for the auto scaling group?

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you have AWS Cli installed, the command looks like this:

aws autoscaling update-auto-scaling-group --auto-scaling-group-name my-auto-scaling-group --health-check-type ELB --health-check-grace-period 60

more info here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/update-auto-scaling-group.html

Comment: Not exact. The relevant parameters are `--desired-capacity`, `--min-size` & `--max-size`

Comment: you're right, I missed that, albeit the link contains full info.